# replace whole word using replace + function + the match argument

Tags: javascript

From the text "myWord Word" I want to get "myWord Replaced" using replace with a function and the match argument. So I wrote the following code but I get "myReplaced Word" instead of "myWord Replaced". Could you please someone help me since I cannot understand well the mechanism of the match argument. Thank you all.

```
<div id="myView"></div>

<script>
    vText = "myWord Word";
    vWord = "Word";

    vText = vText.replace('Word', function(match) {
        if (match == vWord) {
           return 'Replaced';
        } else {
            return match;
        }
    })

    document.getElementById("myView").innerHTML = vText;
</script>
```

Comment: Use regex to replace whole words only: `vText = vText.replace(new RegExp(\`\\b${vWord}\\b\`), "Replace");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex to check whole word match, and the replace the word with desired "Replaced" word.

```
<div id="myView"></div>

<script>
    vText = "myWord Word";
    vWord = "Word";
    var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + vWord + '\\b', "g");
    var vText = ("myWord Word").replace(regex,"Replaced");

    document.getElementById("myView").innerHTML = vText;

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use counter variable to count your matches and then replace a certain word with given match like so:

```html
<div id="myView"></div>

<script>
    let vText = "myWord Word";
    let vWord = "Word";
    let count = 0;

    vText = vText.replace(/Word/g, function(match) {
        count++;
        if (match == vWord && count == 2) {
           return 'Replaced';
        } else {
            return match;
        }
    })

    document.getElementById("myView").innerHTML = vText;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/users/3321784/anita answer and https://stackoverflow.com/users/669576/johnny-mopp comment, it works perfect when the original code becomes:

```
<div id="myView"></div>

<script>
    vText = "myWord Word"; 
    vWord = "Word";
    var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + vWord + '\\b', "g");

    vText = vText.replace(regex, function(match) {
        if (match == vWord) {
           return 'Replaced';
        } else {
            return match;
        }
    })

    document.getElementById("myView").innerHTML = vText;
</script>
```